# cssjanus @noflip with styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am currently using cssJanus for rtl flopping, while using also styled-components,
I am locating the /* @noflip */ on top of the styled-component and no result, in the css file the flag is completely ignored and the margin right is flopped

```
/* @noflip */
const CognitiveFunctionLabelsWrapper: any = styled.div
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
width: 95%;
margin: 0 0 10in 19in;
```